# Swift NSNotificationCenter does not fire

Tags: ios, swift

I have some problems with swift and the NSNotificationCenter-System.
I added the Observer like that:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("disconnected", object: nil, queue: nil) { note in
        self.btConnect.title = "Verbinden"
}
```

and I posted a notification like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("disconnect", object: self)
```

But Nothing happens. the Observer and the Notifier are in differentness classes.
Can someone help me, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You notification name is incorrect: "disconnected" vs "disconnect".

Answer (score 0):

Your both methods need to have the same name. Currently they are `disconnected` and `disconnect`. You have to change the `postNotificationName` parameter from:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("disconnect", object: self)
```

To:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("disconnected", object: self)
```